How to determine the source of a popup window on a Windows 11 computer (popup possibly from Logitech)?
On a new Windows 11 computer, when plugging in the transceiver for a Logitech wireless mouse, a popup suddenly appeared with the text:

Logitech Options+ software
To experience the full functionality of your Logitech device, we recommend installing Logitech Options+ software.
To install Logitech Options+ software, click "install" below.

The popup does not match the theme or appearance of the rest of Windows 11.  The dark theme was enabled in Windows 11, but this popup had a white background, black text, and an atypical white on purple "Install" button.  The borderless popup had no maximize or minimize buttons, but did have a close (X) button in the upper-right corner.
If this wasn't a new device shipped from a factory, I would strongly suspect this popup to be from malware.  After all, it's encouraging the user to install software without the user asking to do anything.
But given that it's a new computer that was in a sealed box, there's a reasonable (but not guaranteed) chance it's not malware, but instead the result of poor decision making by one or more companies (as it trains people to perform the exact type of behaviour that malware will ask them to perform).
Obviously, I didn't click on the popup's "Install" button.
How can I determine the source of this popup in Windows 11?
My guess is that this popup is from Logitech software that Microsoft's Windows 11 includes (or silently downloads), but I don't know.  The computer itself did not include any Logitech products, nor did I manually install anything.
What I tried:

Right-clicking on the popup, but that didn't yield any results.
Looking in the Windows 11 system tray, but no corresponding icon for the popup was there.
Looking in Windows 11's notifications, but nothing related was listed there.


so usually if I ever see a window or whatever that I can't account for, I open Process Explorer, and use the "crosshairs" button in the top panel. drag it over a window, and PS will highlight the process that spawned it. won't work for some low level processes, but its the first thing I'd try

@FrankThomas That's helpful.  Thanks.  What about on a new system on which, intentionally, you don't want any third-party code running yet?  (I realize much of Process Explorer was written by Mark, and last I heard, he was a VP at Microsoft, but everything not included with Windows requires authorization in this case.)

@FrankThomas I should also point out that the popup was taking up about 1/8 of the screen (very approx), so I closed it with its X button.  Thus, the popup is no longer visible.  But it is important to determine if it was just a Windows/Logitech popup or if the system was shipped with malware.

There are multiple "official" ways for hardware makers to ship apps with their drivers. This is what's happening here.

@DanielB Thanks. I agree that's it's most likely the result of legit Logitech software (included with or auto-downloaded by Windows?), but how can I confirm this?  This is obviously how malware appears too.

"How can I determine the source of this popup in Windows 11?" - It's the Logitech device you connected to the system.  It likely has a trivial amount of storage, set to auto-run Logitech software, I have seen this before. If you connected it to a VM, install the software, then unplug it and attach it back to the VM I assume the popup does not happen again?

No, this software isn’t stored on the device. It is part of the “Logitech Download Assistant” not-so-virtual device. // Malware doesn’t just appear.

@DanielB Sorry, when I used the word "appear", I meant "visually appear" or "looks".  IOW, malware attempts often begin with a popup asking the user to install software.
